# SQL command not properly ended on insert query

Tags: oracle

I just want to alter my datas in my table this query seems good but oracle says ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended im new in oracle from mysql.

Here's my code:

```
INSERT  INTO AWACSRECIPEBYWSTYPE(BFGID) VALUES(23) WHERE WSTYPE = 'CLIPBOND';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't put a `WHERE` clause on an `INSERT` statement in Oracle. And [after looking at the MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html) I don't see where you can use a `WHERE` clause like this in MySQL either.

Did you mean to use an `UPDATE` statement?

```
UPDATE AWACSRECIPEBYWSTYPE
  SET BFGID = 23 
  WHERE WSTYPE = 'CLIPBOND'
```

???